# save XML to mysql using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate, clob

I want to save an XML file into LONGTEXT field mysql through hibernate. I'm a bit new to hibernate and really appropriate your advice.

mysql table was created.

**CREATE TABLE `testdata` (
    `TD_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `XML_VAL` LONGTEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`TD_ID`)**

Hibernate entity is also created.

```
@Lob
@Column(name="XML_VAL")
public String getXmlVal() {
    return xmlVal;
}
public void setXmlVal(String xmlVal) {
    this.xmlVal = xmlVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use @Lob.

```
@Column(name = "XML_VAL", length = 65535)
```

You define the length of your text which needs to be inserted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will change this and test this. However I'm a bit stuck on how to convert the XML file to a String. Any advice???